# execute a cron job inside another cron job in node js

Tags: node.js, cron

I m trying to run a cron job inside another cron job in node js. Outside cron job executes one time only
For day 1: Inside cron job  executes 1 time
For Day 2: Inside cron job  executes 2 times
For Day 3: Inside cron job  executes 3 times

```
cron.schedule("0 30 16 * * Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday", function () {
    console.log("inside outside cron job ")
    cron.schedule("10 30 16 * * Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday", function () {
    console.log("inside  cron job 1")
    })
})
```

Why its executing multiple times although i m calling it one time inside a cron job

Comment: Why are you making it nested?

Comment: inside cron job should be executed based on the output from outside cron job. Timings for inside cron job is provided by outside one

Comment: @ Abhishek Mani Timings for inside cron job is provided by outside cronjob

Comment: Outside cron job has to be called daily for changed timings

Comment: Can you clarify the pattern, how you want to run the cron?

Comment: i need the outside cron function to run daily at 01:oo clock morning. inside that cron i have a function which ll give me 3 different timings as output say 4 , 6 , 8. So  cron jobs inside will take 4,6,8 as their timings

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I got it solved. We have to stop the previous  cron job function  before executing next cron job function;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const cron = require("node-cron");
var a;
var b;
var hr;
var min;
var sec;
cron.schedule("0 0 1 * * Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday", function () {
    min = 30;
    hr = 8;
    sec = "0" + ' ' + min + ' ' + hr + ' ' + "* * Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Sunday";
    if (a) {
        a.stop()
    }
    a = cron.schedule(sec, function () {});
    min = 30;
    hr = 16;
    sec = "0" + ' ' + min + ' ' + hr + ' ' + "* * Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Sunday";
    if (b) {
        b.stop();
    }
    b = cron.schedule(sec, function () {});
});
```